# how to define a regular expression that matches two different strings but not the third one

Tags: java

I am new to the concept regular expression in Java. how to define a regular expression which matches the phrase "money", "more money" but not the phrase "no money" ?

Comment: Are there any other possible phrases??

Comment: Use a negative look-behind to prevent a preceeding "no".

Comment: If you only want to match `money` and `more money` and nothing else, `string.matches("money|more money")` would work. If there are some additional constraints, you'll have to list them.

Comment: I should write a method with a string as argument. The output has to be the result whether the string matches or not.

Comment: if you want to match just these two phrases why not use if else?

Comment: What is the exact condition of matching? If you don't want to match a specific substring, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be something like that

`(more )?money`

If you would need more words included:

`(more |less )?money`

Answer (score 1):

To match all strings that contain "money" without "no" in front use negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!no )money
```

Here are some examples. Note that I added `.*` before and after the regular expression to match anywhere in the string:

```
re = ".*(?<!no )money.*"
"blah blah blah money blah blah blah".matches(re)
=> true
"blah blah blah more money blah blah blah".matches(re)
=> true
"blah blah blah no money blah blah blah".matches(re)
=> false
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with regexes ... and I think `"(?<!no)( more)? money"` should do the trick for your example.

But this is not a good way to analyse text:

- It can give false positives; e.g.

  ```
  "domino money"  -- matches
  ```

  and false negatives; e.g.

  ```
  "more    money" -- doesn't match because we didn't allow for multiple spaces.
  ```
- As the language you are testing get richer, you end up with combinatorial explosion in your regexes.  This makes your regexes hard to read / maintain, and can lead to performance problems.